# Copying a file from one shared folder to another using context menu in registry editor

Tags: windows

There is a share path. When user selects one file from the share path and right click to press copy, the selected file should be moved to another folder in same share path. Though we will not be able to customize the default windows copy command, I would like to know is there any other ways through which I can do it. I am really confused searching for the options.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Use the Send To menu. There are questions about using the Send To menu to create utilities and functions accessible in the Right Click menu. Basically, there's a folder you can place shortcuts and these show up in the Send To menu. Put a shortcut to a folder, and it'll do exactly what you want.

Comment: Type `shell:sendto` into Start - Run dialog (Winkey+R) and right click a blank space and choose New - Shortcut and browse to the destination folder. See https://pastebin.com/A2qLw8r3 to see all the `shell:<folder>` you can type.

Answer (score 0):

These are the entries I use to add "Copy to" and "Move to" to the context menu

> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AllFilesystemObjects\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers]

.

> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AllFilesystemObjects\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\Copy To]
>   @="{C2FBB630-2971-11D1-A18C-00C04FD75D13}"

.

> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AllFilesystemObjects\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\Move To]
>   @="{C2FBB631-2971-11D1-A18C-00C04FD75D13}"

.

Copy and paste these into a text file, then rename the file extension to .reg, then right click on it and select merge.